# C++ , Send() function sends extra bytes

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock, winsock2

I am having trouble with a Winsock2 wrapper classes (client-server) and after countless hours of scratching-my-head-in-confusion, I decided it would be better if I asked your opinion.

To be more specific, the problem is that every time I use my Send() function, both the client and the server (not always!) send one or two extra bytes!

For example I use SendBytes("Hello") and the Recv function returns "Hello•" with a '•' or other random characters at the end of the character array.

```
    //main.cpp (Client)
    #include "Socket.h"

    int main() 
    {
        NetworkService::Client cService = NetworkService::Client();
        int res = cService.Initialize("127.0.0.1","20248");
        if(res == 0){
            int local = cService.SendBytes("Hello!");
            printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", local);
            cService.Shutdown();

            char* temp = cService.Recv();
            printf("String Recieved: %s  - Size: %d",temp,strlen(temp));
            printf("\nSTRLEN: %d",strlen("X5"));
        }
        else{
            cService.Clean();
        }
        cService.Close();
        while(!kbhit());
        return 0;
    }
```

Of course, the server sends the string "X5" and the client prints the strlens ...

```
//The result with "X5" as the dummy text:  
String Recieved: X5? - Size: 3 //Notice the extra '?' character  
STRLEN: 2
```

Send // Recieve Functions

```
    int NetworkService::Client::SendBytes(char* lData){
            int local = send( ConnectSocket, lData, (int)strlen(lData), 0 );
            if (local == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                Close();
                return WSAGetLastError();
            }
            return local;
    }

    char* NetworkService::Client::Recv(){
        recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf , recvbuflen, 0);
        return recvbuf;
    }
```

Help would be appreciated ^_^.

Comment: You're not sending the terminating NUL byte in the string.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering so fast! Heres the thing , I added '\0' at the end of the string , but it didn't do anything. I still get random insertions.

Comment: @christian: you already have an implicit \0 there through the string literal. in order for it to be sent though, you need to adjust the size parameter in the send() call. change it from strlen(lData) to strlen(lData)+1 to include the trailing \0. be sure to look up the [strlen()](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) function if you are still unsure why this is necessary.

Comment: It's not really necessary ,I just used it before to compare the length of long strings , because I was messing with the issue with longer than 2 byte strings. I think (ldata)+1 will work , thanks I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me, but

```
 int local;
 (...)
 return (int*)local;
```

What you were trying to achieve? There are many serious problems in your code.

Comment: A warning/error eater , because RecvBytes is int* and Recv returns int.

Comment: I do not understand. You are making pointer from integer which does not make sense. My warning did you mean segfaulting? Well, much clearer idea is to throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way you send data over the network. There are too many errors.

IF you want to send null-terminated strings over the network:

```
int local = send( ConnectSocket, lData, (int)strlen(lData), 0 );
```

as everyone said, you don't actually send the null terminator. You would have sent it if you added 1 to the length. Moreover, with long strings, the `send()` function doesn't guarantee you to send the whole string at once. You have to check for that and resend the missing part.

```
recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf , recvbuflen, 0);
```

You don't check the return value, so you can't know the length of the received string. As you don't send the null byte, the received data is not null-terminated. Also, if null terminator is the only delimiter of more data you send, you'll have to read byte-by-byte (not efficient) not to miss the null terminator to know when to finish. An alternative would be to make your own buffering scheme (so the next read would partially return the result of the previous), or change the protocol to make length of the transported data known beforehand. Also, the same remark about partial reads as with the `send` function applies here.

BTW returning a static/global buffer is not a sign of good code.

Comment: Alright , umm , first of all , what I'm supposed it return? Recv copies the incoming data into a buffer , so when it's done , I return the buffer.Look , I know that sending the data 1 time is error prone and I must send them twice and compare the results in the client. I tried that too , but it doesn't guarantee the results I want , which are the packets to come and go as-is. BTW this is microsofts code , I'm just wrapping everything in a class :).

Comment: Actually increasing the length by 1 and sending over the NUL terminator did the trick! Thanks to Steve-o for noticing first! And everyone else for your tips !!

Comment: @Christian You've changed your code from "happens to not work" to "happens to work". It's still massively broken because it ignores the return value from `recv` and treats as a C-style string data that is not guaranteed to be a C-style string.

Comment: @jpaleck thanks for the answer. Despite it is not marked, it did help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't *really* check the return value of `recv`.

There is a do-while but it doesn't do anything. You return from the function without proper error handling even when `recv` fails, but you will never know it.

Also you don't send the terminating `\0` which isn't necessary bad, depends on what you're trying to do, for example you can add that after receiving.

Comment: I tried adding \0 but it didn't do anything. I still get random characters inserted at the end of the string. So , the question is , still, what's causing the insertions? Thanks for the recv note , i always thought everytime recv adds another byte into the buffer it's return value gets increased by 1.

Comment: Alright, I think It's fixed. I'll give you credits for it ^^.

Comment: No, it's not fixed. How would you know that an error happened? also,  comparing with `=`, seriously?

Comment: I moved recvbuflen to public: and i compare the value RecvBytes returns with it in main.cpp. Of course the data i want to send will be around 3 bytes so there won't be any confusions with the Windows Socket Error codes since the lowest one is 6. I think i forgot to edit the page, oh well.